# UICollectionViewCell with rounded corners AND drop shadow not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, uicollectionviewcell

I want my UICollectionViewCells to have rounded corners and drop shadows but I have run into a problem where it seems I can only have one or the other, but not both.

To just round the corners I use this code in the initialization of the cell:

```
CALayer *layer = [self layer];
[layer setCornerRadius:4];
[layer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
[layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

To just add a drop shadow I use this code in the initialization of the cell:

```
CALayer *layer = [self layer];
[layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
[layer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
[layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.5f)];
[layer setShadowRadius:8.0f];
[layer setShadowOpacity:0.2f];
[layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:layer.cornerRadius] CGPath]];
```

To try and have rounded corners and a drop shadow I use this code in the initialization of the cell:

```
CALayer *layer = [self layer];
[layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
[layer setCornerRadius:4];
[layer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
[layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.5f)];
[layer setShadowRadius:8.0f];
[layer setShadowOpacity:0.2f];
[layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:layer.cornerRadius] CGPath]];
```

but this results in the drop shadow only.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found a work around. I added an extra UIView (bgView) in the UICollectionViewCell in Interface Builder and put all the content of the cell into that bgView. I also made a property in the cell and wired an IBOutlet up to the bgView. In the init for the cell I added the drop shadow to the cell's layer. Then in a configCell method which I call in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: I added the rounded corners to the new bgView. I also had to make sure to set the backgroundColor of the UICollectionViewCell to be clear. This works, but I still feel that it shouldn't be so convoluted to do.

Answer (score 31):

Works for me great:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        ...
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
        ...
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: the maskToBounds will crop out the shadow effect. Lal Krishna below as a better answer

Answer (score 23):

If you place all your subviews into the `UICollectionViewCell` content view, which you probably are, you can set the shadow on the cell's layer and the border on the `contentView`'s layer to achieve both results.

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.0f);
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
cell.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds cornerRadius:cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
```

#### Swift 4.0

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
```

Comment: Should set inside layoutSubviews:   cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

Answer (score 2):

I think I ran into a similar issue. My problem was that clipping in my subviews of the `UICollectionViewCell` didn't work properly with shadows and rounded borders. The exact same code worked just fine before when I had that view (as a standard `UIView` subclass though) in a `UIScrollView`.

So long story short, I moved all this setup from the `initWithCoder` to a later place after getting it from `-dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Solved the problem for me. Seems like `UICollectionViews` are doing something I wouldn't expect to their cells' layers at some point?

Comment: Yeah, this is strange. However, doing the setup in the `applyLayoutAttributes:` method of the cell subclass worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is tricky moment. Cutting corners and dropping shadow is mutually exclusive function in one layer. Dropping shadow is frame extension process, but corners is the process of masking to bounds.

Solution is in function separation. I recommend setup shadow for the cell layer, but cut corners for contentView layer of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a subclass to make the collection just make sure you do the following.

```
CALayer *layer = [self layer];
[layer setCornerRadius:_cornerRadius];
[layer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
[layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0,4.0)];
[layer setShadowRadius:6.0f];
[layer setShadowOpacity:0.25];
[layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:layer.cornerRadius] CGPath]];

self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = _cornerRadius;
self.contentView.layer.borderWidth= _borderWidth;
self.contentView.layer.borderColor = _borderColor.CGColor;
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

works like a charm.