# UITableViewCell Layer Shadow Overlap Cell above

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, calayer, shadow

Everything is in the Title.

I have a UITableView with cells. The **cells** has a **Shadow** (self.layer.shadow...).

The problem is that the **shadow** of **one cell** is **Overlapping** the cell **above**.
How can I prevent this behavior ?

[image]

And here is the code in my cell :

```
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: screenshot please? And could you show somecode

Comment: @LalKrishna it's actually the cell above and not "below" like I wrote. But the problem is still the same

Comment: Can you try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44820559/4061501

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for adding shadow :-

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

Comment: Still the same ! I tried to isolate the content in the contentView, and the shadow directly on the root layer with the offset, but nothing

Comment: @AlexisDarnat It seems like you have not given the spacing between `TableView Cells` and that's why these shows overlapping. So you can do one thing, - Take a `UIView` in Tableview cell and put it's constraint trailing,leading,top,bottom as 8 points and then apply my above code on this `UIView` outlet rather than on `content view` of `Tableviewcell`